# How do I monitor for specific command line errors (Windows) ?

Tags: batch-file

I need to have a batch file with multiple drive mapping statements like this:

```
@echo off
net use Q: \\serve\share
```

When the drive is already connected, I get system error 85. How can I monitor for the 85 error and take my own action (like a cheap goto already_connected)?  If it's any error other than an 85, I want to see the message displayed (or grab it from a variable and display it... whatever).

I've tried some samples I found, but I can't seem to suppress the system error display and I can't figure out how to trap specifically for the 85 error.  If I could get a sample of how to do the error suppression, trapping, etc I can probably craft the rest of the code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking for error after map, check for map before error

**edited** to correct an error in existing map search

```
    call :doMap q: "\\server\share"
    ....

:doMap drive share
    rem search for drive map in server
    net use | find /i "%~1" | find /i "%~2" > nul
    if errorlevel 1 (

        rem if not found, test if drive letter is mapped
        rem and remove map if needed
        net use | find /i "%~1" > nul && net use "%~1" /delete >nul

        rem map drive to server share
        net use %~1 "%~2" > nul

    ) 
    goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great. Is the call you have indicating that the rest of the code would be in a separate file that is called as needed for each drive to be checked/mapped?

Comment: No, all the code goes into a batch file. It is designed as a subroutine inside your main batch file. Simply add `:doMap` subroutine at the end of your script. When a map is needed, instead of calling `net use` and having to handle the error, use `call :doMap letter share` as the sample indicates.

Comment: did you intentionally use both `findstr` and `find`? if so, why?

Comment: @mattwilkie, it was intentional, but it also included an error (corrected now). `findstr` is more flexible but heavier to load, so if `find` is enough to solve the problem use it. I included `findstr` to shorten the initial filter, but i did not test it thoroughly and there was an error in the logic, so, removed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
net use Q: \\serve\share 2>&1 | find "85" &&(
  echo error 85
)
```

??